# UISlider thumb image with clear background shows track behind it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uislider

How can I set a clear thumb background on `UISlider` so that the track is not visible behind the thumb?

When I use `setThumbImage:forState:` and pass a partially transparent image, the slider's minimum track and maximum track image/colors are visible behind the thumb image:

[image: track visible behind thumb]

I want it to look like in the iOS Camera application, where the "transparent" thumb image circle clips the track background color:

[image: iOS camera slider]

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra what's the question?

Comment: @matt its make the view behind the thumbnail (rounded image) transparent while thumbnail is moving,  as the native camera app

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I never noticed that. My guess is that the thumb is simply a transparent image, as in the original question (first screen shot). The trick would then lie in the slicing of the resizable `minimumTrackImage` and `maximumTrackImage`. The right end of the former, and the left end of the latter, would be transparent and of fixed size — exactly half the diameter of the thumb's circle.

Comment: @matt The slicing doesn't work because the maximum track images extend the length of the track.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys Yeah, I found that out.

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR

In short, there is no simple API of `UISlider` that recreates this behavior.

*Precondition: Per the question, I am only demonstrating how to make the thumb appear transparent and not show the track. I am not attempting to recreate the camera's slider exactly.*

#### Ideal Solution

The ideal solution would be to create minimum and maximum track images that take advantage of [cap insets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624102-resizableimage) to keep a portion of the track from being filled in. I say this is ideal because it is straightforward and relatively performant. Unfortunately, `UISlider` does 2 things that prevents us from using this method.

1. The maximum track image is actually the same width as the entire track, but it is contained in view that has `clipsToBounds` set to true. The maximum track's super view is resized and clips the maximum track to ensure it is never visible on the leading side of the thumb.

   Disabling `clipsToBounds` on the entire hierarchy lets us see this in the view debugger.

[image]

2. The minimum track `UIImageView` is resized, but when one calls `setMinimumTrackImage` on `UISlider` it actually creates a different resizable image. This one took a while to figure out, but it can be demonstrated by inspecting the memory addresses.

   [image]

#### Alternate Solution: Changing the Images to Match the Value

Taking what I learned from my initial investigation, we can generate the images as the value changes. This is not the most efficient approach because it requires creating many images over and over. But, it fits within the original question's parameters. Note, you can only do it effectively with "continuous" sliders since it relies on value updates. On the plus side, this can easily be extended to draw more interesting track images, (like the one in the camera).

Here's the result, I made the thumb quite large so you can easily see that it is transparent.

[image]

Here's the class:

```
class TransparentThumbSlider: UISlider {

    let thumbWidth: CGFloat = 40

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        setThumbImage(TransparentThumbSlider.thumbImage(diameter: thumbWidth, color: .blue), for: .normal)

        addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateTrackImages), for: .valueChanged)

        updateTrackImages()
    }

    static func thumbImage(diameter: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let strokeWidth: CGFloat = 4
        let halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2
        let totalRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: diameter, height: diameter)
        let strokeRect = CGRect(x: halfStrokeWidth,
                                y: halfStrokeWidth,
                                width: diameter - strokeWidth,
                                height: diameter - strokeWidth)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: totalRect.size)
        let image = renderer.image { context in
            context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
            context.cgContext.setLineWidth(strokeWidth)
            context.cgContext.strokeEllipse(in: strokeRect)
        }

        return image
    }

    static func trackImage(colored color: UIColor,
                           thumbWidth: CGFloat,
                           trackWidth: CGFloat,
                           value: CGFloat,
                           flipped: Bool) -> UIImage {

        let fraction = flipped ? 1 - value : value
        let adjustableWidth = (trackWidth - thumbWidth)
        let halfThumbWidth = thumbWidth / 2
        let fudgeFactor: CGFloat = 2

        var totalRect: CGRect

        var coloredRect: CGRect
        if flipped {
            totalRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: trackWidth, height: 2)
            coloredRect = CGRect(
                x: adjustableWidth * value + thumbWidth - fudgeFactor,
                y: 0,
                width: adjustableWidth * fraction + (halfThumbWidth - fudgeFactor),
                height: 2)
        } else {
            totalRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: adjustableWidth * fraction + halfThumbWidth, height: 2)
            coloredRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: adjustableWidth * fraction, height: 2)
        }

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: totalRect.size)
        let image = renderer.image { context in
            context.cgContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(coloredRect)
        }

        return image
    }

    @objc func updateTrackImages() {

        let trackWidth = trackRect(forBounds: bounds).width

        let minimumImage = TransparentThumbSlider.trackImage(
            colored: .green,
            thumbWidth: thumbWidth,
            trackWidth: trackWidth,
            value: CGFloat(value),
            flipped: false)
        setMinimumTrackImage(minimumImage, for: .normal)

        let maximumImage = TransparentThumbSlider.trackImage(
            colored: .yellow,
            thumbWidth: thumbWidth,
            trackWidth: trackWidth,
            value: CGFloat(value),
            flipped: true)
        setMaximumTrackImage(maximumImage, for: .normal)
    }

    var previousBounds: CGRect = .zero

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Prevent layout loop
        if previousBounds != bounds {
            previousBounds = bounds
            updateTrackImages()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that (a) you went the extra mile on this one and (b) you should get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with it in action to show that this should accomplish OP's goal:

[image]

The short version is that I use a UIImage of the background, with the following extension applied to it to add a border.

```
extension UIImage {
    func addRoundBorder(width: CGFloat,
                        color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let square = CGSize(width: min(size.width, size.height) + width * 2,
                            height: min(size.width, size.height) + width * 2)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        imageView.image = self
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width / 2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = width
        imageView.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return self }
        imageView.layer.render(in: context)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result ?? self
    }
}
```

Then, I bring in a `UIImage` of my background and call the extension, using the result as my new thumbnail image.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "circle")!.addRoundBorder(width: 3.0, color: .yellow)
slider.setThumbImage(image, for: .normal)
```

While this is just for demonstrative purposes, I would recommend using an `#imageLiteral` to avoid the force cast.

The following screenshot is comparing the sample image provided by OP via the iOS camera application against the one I implemented as seen below. Due to the size of each, the quality of the Apple one allows for better detail in the comparison.

[image]

Regarding the comment by @Alladinian, the issue I see is that the background has a light texture to it, and the use of the border provides a visual way to break up where the button merges with the background. By using the OP's background, it appeared to provide a similar visual result. However, a more challenging background such as an image would definitely expose my design and produce an undesirable result.

Comment: Just to note (I also got confused by the question at first) that the OP wants a _transparent_ thumb that cuts through the track (imagine that a video is playing full screen in the background - just like the zoom slider in the camera app - you should be able to see the dynamic content inside the thumb) and not just a static image that gives the illusion of transparency by matching the background...

Comment: @Alladinian I see. I suppose it depends on what background will ultimately be behind the slider. Assuming the example posted of a gray textured background, that is less of an issue. However, if there is going to be a photo / video, etc, then my answer would also fail. In that case, it would appear that they would need a custom slider built.

Answer (score -4):

You Have to add Thumb image which only has circular border and which is transparent only possible option as far as i know